# Помогите найти api сайта

Tags: api

Хочу получать расписание через апи сайта а найти его не смог https://www.asu.ru/timetable/students/25/2129436979/

Comment: обратитесь в службу поддержки данного ресурса за интересующей информацией

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Answer (score 0):

Раз вы его не нашли, то: его нет или плохо искали (хотя первое наиболее вероятнее). Единственный способ брать данные с сайта - это его парсить, например Selenium Webdriver, или просто получать его html содержимое и уже самому как xml парсить с помощью xpath.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).